# Give an ID based on the total number of unique appearances in each group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying hard to solve this issue for long time and I would like your guidance and help
I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
col1 <- c("a","a","b", "a","b","c","a","c","d")
replicate <- c("rep1","rep1","rep1","rep2","rep2","rep2","rep3","rep3","rep3")
df = data.frame(col1, replicate)

  col1 replicate
1    a      rep1
2    a      rep1
3    b      rep1
4    a      rep2
5    b      rep2
6    c      rep2
7    a      rep3
8    c      rep3
9    d      rep3
```

I would like to create another column which contains the number of times each element
of the ***col1*** occurs in the column ***replicate*** but I do not want to take into consideration duplicates in each replicate. I want my data to look like this

```
  col1 replicate  ID
1    a      rep1  3
2    a      rep1  3
3    b      rep1  2
4    a      rep2  3
5    b      rep2  2
6    c      rep2  2
7    a      rep3  3
8    c      rep3  2
9    d      rep3  1
```

and this is because "a" occurs in all 3 replicates
"b" exists in  rep1 and rep2
"c" in rep2 and rep3
and "d" only in rep3

Comment: use `n_distinct()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>% group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate(ID = n_distinct(col1, replicate))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   col1 [4]
  col1  replicate    ID
  <chr> <chr>     <int>
1 a     rep1          3
2 a     rep1          3
3 b     rep1          2
4 a     rep2          3
5 b     rep2          2
6 c     rep2          2
7 a     rep3          3
8 c     rep3          2
9 d     rep3          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `uniqueN`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ID := uniqueN(paste(col1, replicate)), col1]
```

-ouptut

```
df
   col1 replicate ID
1:    a      rep1  3
2:    a      rep1  3
3:    b      rep1  2
4:    a      rep2  3
5:    b      rep2  2
6:    c      rep2  2
7:    a      rep3  3
8:    c      rep3  2
9:    d      rep3  1
```